# Make balance report with previous

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to make daily report from an SQL table which contains ID (user id), Timestamp, Balance Transactions.

My quest: Every transactions have been stored in the table. I have to know the summary all user's balance on every day.

For examle:

```
27/06/2016 8:10 User1 50$

27/06/2016 10:22 User1 75$

27/06/2016 11:32 User2 10$

28/06/2016 09:22 User3 40$

28/06/2016 17:35 User1 22$
```

In this case the results have to be the following:

27/06/2016: 85$ (75+10) because last user1's balance 75 and user2 10

28/06/2016: 72$ (22+10+40) because last user1's balance 22 and user2 10 (it was modified on yesterday but I have to count it!!!) and user3 22$

Please help.

Thanks

My solution but it is not correct: Only provide result if transaction was on the day and does not add previous day result.

## Here are the requests I tried so far :

### Request 1 :

```
USE DB1;
GO
WITH cte (bin, currency, id, currentbalance, currentledgerbalance, dt) as ( SELECT bin, w.currency, w.id,t.currentbalance, t.currentledgerbalance, t.dt
FROM [DB1].[Tb1] b
inner join [tb2] c 
on b.[id]=c.[id]
inner join tb3 w
on c.id=w.id and w.currency=b.currency
inner join [DB1].[tb4] t
on t.walletid=w.id )
, CTE2 (bin,currency,id,currentbalance,currentledgerbalance,dt) as (
  select *
  from cte
  where dt in (select MAX(dt) FROM cte GROUP BY currency,id,DAY(dt), MONTH(dt), YEAR(dt))
)
```

### Request 2 :

```
select currency
,cast(dt as date) as stat_day
,sum(currentbalance) as currentbalance 
from CTE2 
GROUP BY currency,cast(dt as date) 
order by stat_day go
```

Comment: What if in 29/06/2016 again User2's transaction would not show up? Do you have to count User2's transaction from 27/06/2016 in 29/06/2016?

Comment: Only the last update needs (because this is the state of every accounts)
Yes

Comment: For example if no transaction on 29th then I have to get the same result as previous day. Or if a new account modified on 29th only, I have to add these balance to 28th balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what other tables involved in the solution. Just giving you a generic solution based on the query given:

```
---Creating a test table
create table usertrans (tid int identity, tdate date, uname varchar(30),balance int);
insert into usertrans values ('06/27/2017','user1',50);
insert into usertrans values ('06/27/2017','user1',75);
insert into usertrans values ('06/27/2017','user2',10);
insert into usertrans values ('06/28/2017','user3',40);
insert into usertrans values ('06/28/2017','user1',22);

  select * from usertrans


-- Retrieving (2017-06-28) balance

with UMaxTrans(UName,TID)
AS(
select uname, max(tid) AS TID from usertrans
WHERE TDate < = '2017-06-28'
group by uname)
select CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS 'Today' , sum(Balance) FROM UserTrans UT
INNER JOIN UMaxTrans UMT ON UT.TID  = UMT.TID;



-- Retrieving (2017-06-27) balance

with UMaxTrans(UName,TID)
AS(
select uname, max(tid) AS TID from usertrans
WHERE TDate < = '2017-06-27'  
group by uname)
select CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS 'Today' , sum(Balance) FROM UserTrans UT
INNER JOIN UMaxTrans UMT ON UT.TID  = UMT.TID;
```

**Logic:**
We have users and the balance might get change any number of times in a given day but while calculating the total balance from all users we have to consider the latest transaction from the user. Thats what we are doing in the query. We are getting the maximum transaction ID for a given user and thats the latest balance.